# Find ids of non unique rows in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my PostgreSQL database I have table schools which has the following columns

```
id - primary key
school_identifier - string
school_name - string
```

Now I want to find ids of schools which identifier is not unique. How can I do this in SQL?

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING count(*) > 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
select id from schools where school_identifier in (
SELECT school_identifier
FROM schools
GROUP BY school_identifier
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Here I am first getting duplicate school_identifiers in a subquery. For those, I am getting id by comparing school_identifier from subquery to main table.

Answer (score 2):

You can group by `school_identifier` and use `COUNT`. Next you need to filter only records that have count > 1.

```
SELECT school_identifier, COUNT(*)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY school_identifier
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: id is the primary key... Do group by school_identifier instead.